# The usage of FQCN in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase

I would like to know if there is any downside to using `use` instead of using a FQCN to refer to classes in TYPO3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No downside really. You only need to be careful if you use two classes with the same name which only differ in their namespaces, but that is documented in the PHP documentation. 
The advantages are obvious : improved readability, less typing. Many IDEs will help you with using `use`. 
Just use the FQCN in PhpDoc comments.

Answer (score 3):

There are some places where you must use the fully qualified name of classes:

- In `@var` annotations of class members that are also annotated with `@inject`
- In controller action parameters that do not use type hints
- Maybe more places, don't know

If you don't use the FQCN, reflection stops working in these places, so dependency injection fails, and type conversion for parameters of actions does not work ("Could not determine type for parameter foo of myAction" or something similar is the exception message).

I've heard that there were attempts to make non-FQCNs work in these places, but they seem to have failed.